# How to request for token in REST Api in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I have **consumer key** and **secret key** for `Rest API` in magento2

**How Can I get token from magento side?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are the consumer and secret key you have for Rest API, but as per I know the way to get the Token for mostly requests to the API is this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://local.magento2.com/rest/en_ae/V1/integration/admin/token \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{
  "username": "admin_user",
  "password": "admin_password"
}'
```

Let me know if this is what you was looking for.